# Is batching useful when select qualifies on multiple single parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, batching

My Oracle 11g SQL query looks something like this:

```
select distinct(p.person_id) 
from   person p, activity a 
where  p.name like '?' 
  and p.active=1 
  and p.create_date<=systimestamp 
  and p.end_date>=systimestamp 
  and p.person_id = a.person_id
```

Additionally, I am dynamically adding a couple of date time qualifications (on the activity table) to the query above based on certain conditions.

I am using a batching framework written over JDBC but my question is - Is batching really needed in this case or is just an unnecessary overhead? All the examples which I've seen involved an `in` parameter for the purpose of qualifications.

Also, is there a good resource to read about this stuff? I couldn't find any decent sources.

Thanks

Comment: Cant you make it a procedure? Better performance.

Comment: OracleUser - Not sure about that but is batching useful at all in this context?

Comment: Batching is usefull for reducing a number of roundtrips to the database when you have many updates (insert+update+delete statements). You can't batch SELECT statements in JDBC.

Comment: kordirko - Good to know, thanks. It seems our batching framework is different from the actual notion of batching.Our framework seems to expand the SQL select statement to include multiple parameters.

Comment: @OracleUser - better performance? [citation needed]

Comment: @APC I meant.. combining multiple select statements into one pl sql transaction by putting the results into user defined types..!  i understood this question as ,OP wants to do the select for multiple values over a Column.. so, instead making a big IN clause, may be we can join it with a PL/SQL table or something.. I get the intention of your comment.  You can always let me know, if I am wrong. Thanks.